# How to convert $-2 - 2\sqrt{3}i$ into exponential form?

Tags: complex-numbers

Given the complex number $z = -2 -2\sqrt{3} i$, convert it to its exponential form. Furthermore, calculate $z^6$.

The way I would solve this, is calculate $r = 4$;

And argument $\theta = \arctan (\frac{-2\sqrt{3}}{-2}) = \frac{1}{3}\pi $ which makes $ z = 4e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i}$ and so $z^6 = 4096e^{2\pi i}$. But the solution confidently claims $\theta = \arctan (\frac{-2\sqrt{3}}{-2}) - \pi$ and later $z^6 = 4096$. (Yes, just 4096, nothing else). Is the solution simply wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Read this article to see how to compute argument correctly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation.

Comment: @Ennar ah I didn't know that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you read here. Possible duplicate! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293260/argument-of-a-complex-number-as-arctan

Answer (score 1):

First, you can only use the formula $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$ if $x+iy$ is in the 1st or 4th quadrant. What quadrant contains $-2-2\sqrt{3}i$?

And on top of that, can you somehow simplify $e^{2 \pi i}$?

Comment: Aha, thanks for you input (genuinely). But I'm not exactly sure which quadrant contains this complex number. Maybe the 3rd? If only there was a forum on the web where people asked math - related questions and other people answered these questions instead of asking a question in return because they figured out the person who asked the question is just getting into complex numbers and doesn't really understand what's going on. (Please help me I actually don't know what you are talking about).

Comment: @T.Feix Unfortunately, MathSE is committed to giving priority to creating a high quality repository of questions and answers, rather than giving priority to education.

Comment: People want to help you understand. You are being invited to think about something a little. A bit of thought on your part will help you much more than being fed an answer. What are you going to do with a fed answer, memorize it? Accept that when you ask a question you are entering a dialogue and be open to that.

Comment: @user2661923 my question is super specific to begin with - a higher quality answer would include the correct formula to calculate this argument, which I thankfully know now because of a comment underneath my post. It would also include the correct way to simplify this complex number, and an overall explanation of how arguments are calculated in general, instead of a question, as previously mentioned. For this reason (and also because I want to understand it) I specifically didn't ask for "just the solution".

Comment: @Paul exactly. E. g. now I memorized how to correctly calculate the argument based on the signs in front of a and b. I could've also thought long and hard about how to correctly calculate the argument, but I would have wasted that time because I didn't know that.

Comment: @T.Feix I am not attempting to justify the MathSE protocol, merely explain it.  For what it's worth, virtually no MathSE posted question that I have seen (from me or anyone else) that followed 
[this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
has been downvoted. Instead, such questions are almost always upvoted, with 
MathSE reviewers going out of their way to try to give a full and complete answer to the question.  ...see next comment

Comment: @T.Feix Your posted question is a long way away from following the protocol in the linked article.

Answer (score 1):

In the third quadrant, the angle is measured from the negative $x$-axis.

The corrected argument is:
$$\theta = \pi + \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) $$

For $z=-2 - 2\sqrt{3}i$, $a = -2$ and $b = -2\sqrt{3}$, so:
$$ \theta = \pi + \arctan\left(\frac{-2\sqrt{3}}{-2}\right) = \pi + \arctan(\sqrt{3}) = \pi + \frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{4\pi}{3} $$

$$z=-2 - 2\sqrt{3}i =re^{i\theta}= 4e^{i(4\pi/3)} $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But just to clarify, you are saying that both I and the solution are wrong?

Comment: For my humble opinion. Yes. I have always done this with vectors and then with complex numbers.

Comment: This confuses me. Because the comment linking to a Wikipedia - article under my question seems to support $- \pi$ instead of $+ \pi$, and that would render the original solution correct. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: @T.Feix I think that Wikipedia considers the angle in clockwise direction instead of counterclockwise.

Comment: The again, $\tan$ is periodic but I hardly think $e^{-\frac{2 \pi}{3}i} = e^{\frac{4 \pi}{3}i}$.

Comment: I see. Then I will consult the author of the solution that was provided to me.

Comment: @T.Feix Look here https://www.unife.it/ing/informazione/analisi-matematica-Ib/lezioni-ed-esercizi/lezione-2-geometria-dei-numeri-complessi to pag. 7 is the same of Wikipedia.

Comment: @T.Feix While $-\frac{2 \pi}{3}i \ne \frac{4 \pi}{3}i$, it's true that $e^{-\frac{2 \pi}{3}i} = e^{\frac{4 \pi}{3}i}$. Just that the principal argument value that your solution chooses is different from the one in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\exp\left(\log 4 +(2 k \pi-\frac{2 \pi }{3})\,i\right)$$

$k\in \mathbb{Z}$. [Check :](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Exp%5B%20Log%5B4%5D%20-%20%202%20Pi%2F3%20I%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use well-known specific values of trigonometric functions and Euler's formula: $$
 - 2 - 2\sqrt 3\, {\rm i} = 4\left( { - \tfrac{1}{2} - \tfrac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}{\rm i}} \right) = 4\left( {\cos \left( { - \tfrac{{2\pi }}{3} + 2\pi n} \right) + {\rm i}\sin \left( { - \tfrac{{2\pi }}{3} + 2\pi n} \right)} \right) = 4{\rm e}^{\left( { - \frac{{2\pi }}{3} + 2\pi n} \right){\rm i}} ,
$$
with any $n\in \mathbb Z$.